# Block Update Profile Errors

Tags: hooks, errors, profiles

I'm trying to validate the form users submit when updating their profile data.  I've hooked into user_profile_update_errors.  It prints errors correctly to the user, however, it still allows the errors to be applied to the User's profile.  The errors displayed are not actually enforced.

How can I prevent erred profile entries from being saved and instead block them?

Thanks

```
 function tml_profile_errors( $errors ) {
   if ( empty( $_POST['state'] ) )
       $errors->add( 'empty_missing_', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please enter your state.' );

   return $errors;
 }
 add_filter( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'tml_profile_errors' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

First, Jeff Farthing of theme-my-login pointed out that I was using add_filter instead of add_action, and helped to craft the first code below, however it still has the same problem, so this is a step in the right direction but is not my solution:

```
function tml_profile_errors( &$errors ) {
    if ( empty( $_POST['state'] ) )
        $errors->add( 'empty_missing_', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please enter your state.' );
}
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'tml_profile_errors' );
```

Second, I added the same validation step inside of my 'personal_options_update' and 'edit_user_profile_update' actions using the code below.  Since this is run during the save step, it will prevent the user from saving and invalid value.  There are a lot more fields than just 'state' for the form, which is why the example below uses a nested if rather than an && operator:

```
function tml_edit_user_profile_update( $user_id ) {
     if ( current_user_can('edit_user',$user_id) ) {
         if ( !empty( $_POST['state'] ) )
           update_user_meta( $user_id, 'state', $_POST['state'] );
     }
 }
add_action('personal_options_update', 'tml_edit_user_profile_update');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'tml_edit_user_profile_update');
```